# How can I back up my Mac Auto Correct & Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: macos

Under `System Preferences > Keyboard >  Text`, I have a lot of entries under Auto Correct. How can I back these up to transfer to a different machine?

Same with the shortcuts under  `System Preferences > Keyboard >  Shortcuts`. How can I back these up to transfer to a different machine?

I am doing a clean install going from Sierra to High Sierra. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

For text substitutions, the answer is here (and being OsX we should have guessed it by ourselves): https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204006

Not sure why you want to export the shortcuts, unless you customized a lot of them... however someone else asked for it: https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/4fx2wo/is_there_a_way_to_saveexport_keyboard_shortcuts/